# Search by Order Contents

Tags: orders, customer

We have rental products that are constantly going out to customers and coming back to us. However, remembering what customers have which products is a pain.

Is there any way to search by a product / order to see what customer currently possesses a product? Or better yet, to see the historical records of this product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL query might serve as a starting point. It gives you a historical overview of orders concerning the given SKU. You might want to add some more columns or constraints like not showing canceled orders at all or the like.

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(' ', `o`.`customer_firstname`, `o`.`customer_lastname`) 'Customer Name',
    `o`.`customer_email` 'Customer Email',
    `i`.`sku` 'SKU',
    `o`.`created_at` 'Order Date',
    `o`.`state` 'Order State',
    `o`.`status` 'Order Status'
FROM `sales_flat_order` `o`
JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` `i`
ON `o`.`entity_id`=`i`.`order_id`
WHERE `i`.`sku` = 'ENTER YOUR SKU HERE'
ORDER BY `o`.`created_at` DESC
```